# How to set jdbc/partitionColumn type to Date in spark 2.4.1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to retrieve data from oracle using spark-sql-2.4.1 version.
I tried to set the JdbcOptions as below :

```
    .option("lowerBound", "31-MAR-02");
    .option("upperBound", "01-MAY-19");
    .option("partitionColumn", "data_date");
    .option("numPartitions", 240);
```

But gives error :

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
        at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:204)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.toInternalBoundValue(JDBCRelation.scala:179)
```

Then tried as below

```
    .option("lowerBound", "2002-03-31"); //changed the date format
    .option("upperBound", "2019-05-02");
    .option("partitionColumn", "data_date"); 
    .option("numPartitions", 240);
```

Still no luck.
So what is the correct way to pass the date as "lower/upperBound"?
Is there a way to specify/set option parameter data Type ?

**Part-2**
Checked the options properly.
they were overwritten in between before executing the query.
So corrected it. ... now that error resolved.

But  for below options:

```
.option("lowerBound", "2002-03-31 00:00:00"); 
.option("upperBound", "2019-05-01 23:59:59");
.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Query String :

```
query ->  ( SELECT * FROM MODEL_VALS ) T
```

It is throwing another error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P022, instance nj0005

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Comment: can you paste the full code for reading?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using Oracle, see: [apache/spark/.../OracleIntegrationSuite.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/connector/docker-integration-tests/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/OracleIntegrationSuite.scala#L428)

```scala
val df1 = spark.read.format("jdbc")
      .option("url", jdbcUrl)
      .option("dbtable", "datetimePartitionTest")
      .option("partitionColumn", "d")
      .option("lowerBound", "2018-07-06")
      .option("upperBound", "2018-07-20")
      .option("numPartitions", 3)
      // oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp defaults to true. If this flag is not disabled, column d
      // (Oracle DATE) will be resolved as Catalyst Timestamp, which will fail bound evaluation of
      // the partition column. E.g. 2018-07-06 cannot be evaluated as Timestamp, and the error
      // message says: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff].
      .option("oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp", "false")
      .option("sessionInitStatement", "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD'")
      .load()
```

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this question as I am solving a similar problem. 
But in this case Spark 2.4.2 is sending date in format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ssss' to Oracle and it returned "Not a valid month" as it expects 'dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss.ssss'. 
To solve that I followed: [Spark GitHub Link](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/18411)
, it says:

> Override beforeFetch method in OracleDialect to finish the following
>   two things:
>
> Set Oracle's NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT to "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF" to
>   match java.sql.Timestamp format. Set Oracle's NLS_DATE_FORMAT to
>   "YYYY-MM-DD" to match java.sql.Date format.

And it solved the issue. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The given parameters have type timestamp, but you're providing the only date. Timestamp has format as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, so you need to provide your dates as `2002-03-31 00:00:00` and `2019-05-01 23:59:59` correspondingly...

Comment: thank you so much Alex you are always with helping hand... one more thing when i see the source code of v2.4.1 i see it as          private def toInternalBoundValue(value: String, columnType: DataType): Long = columnType match {
    case _: NumericType => value.toLong
    case DateType => DateTimeUtils.fromJavaDate(Date.valueOf(value)).toLong
    case TimestampType => DateTimeUtils.fromJavaTimestamp(Timestamp.valueOf(value))
  }  So why it is not considering it as "DateType" ?

Comment: Changed it as   

.option("lowerBound", "2002-03-31 00:00:00" );
.option("upperBound", "2019-05-01 23:59:59");


But still getting same error : 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

Comment: just checked, worked just fine with these dates. Can you remove the `;` between the calls to `option` ?

Comment: Sorry i am using java code ... so ";" is must. May I know how/where are you testing it ?

Comment: please check this  https://gist.github.com/shatestest/34c6f7fda3e24499080b6d03e2bbb45d

Comment: let me know if any confusion in understanding my code.

Comment: please check this gist.github.com/shatestest/34c6f7fda3e24499080b6d03e2bbb45d

Comment: updated with SampleSourceData ... https://gist.github.com/shatestest/34c6f7fda3e24499080b6d03e2bbb45d

Comment: I suspect that somehow options aren't persisted in data frame... For me `Timestamp.valueOf("2019-05-01 23:59:59");` works just fine - returning timestamp

Comment: when i debug I see options set to DataFrameReader perfectly fine.    Map(driver -> oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver, 
numPartitions -> 2000,
 timestampFormat -> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, 
upperBound -> 2019-05-01 23:59:59.0,
lowerBound -> 2002-03-31 00:00:00.0,
partitionColumn -> DATA_DATE,
url -> jdbc:oracle:thin:@, 
user -> user1,  password -> pwd1,
customSchema -> DATA_DATE TIMESTAMP, DATA_ITEM_VALUE_NUMERIC DECIMAL(38, 15) , MODEL_FAMILY_ID INTEGER , FISCAL_YEAR INTEGER , FISCAL_QUARTER  INTEGER,
 fetchsize -> 10000)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192780/discussion-between-shyam-and-alex-ott).

Comment: @ user10938362 any suggestion to fix above error i.e.  Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

Answer (score 1):

all of the following options must be set in this way in order for it to work:

```
spark.read
      .option("header", true)
      .option("inferSchema", true)
      .option("timestampFormat", "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a")
      .csv("PATH_TO_CSV")
```

Comment: @Alex Ott , yes earlier error was about the options overwriting as you mentioned. Now i fixed , but now getting "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string" .      request to have a look at "part 2" of question

Comment: Unfortunately I did use Oracle ~13 years ago... But I remember that they had very detailed manuals on every error code